# how to camelcase filename?

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to modify `cla` snippet but failed too.

This is the snippet

```
snippet cla class .. end
class ${1:`substitute(Filename(), '^.', '\u&', '')`}
    ${2}
```

It takes filename automatically and converts it like this

```
 this_is_filename.rb =>  This_is_filename
```

I am not happy with it. I rather want it like

```
this_is_filename.rb => ThisIsFilename
```

How to do that ?

Comment: What language are you doing this in?  A regex like [`(?<=\A|_)(\w)`](http://regex101.com/r/jX7gG6) works, but you'll still need to upper case the match group and remove the leftover `_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This converts the filename to camelCase

```
substitute(Filename(), '_\(.\)', '\U\1', 'g')
```

However it looks like you want PascalCase. This should work for PascalCase

```
substitute(Filename(), '\%(^\|_\)\(.\)', '\U\1', 'g')
```

Comment: + 1 for `PascalCase`, never heard about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what language you are using, but [`(?:\A|_)(\w)`](http://regex101.com/r/hA3oT5) will capture the first letter along with `_` followed by a letter.  However, only the letter (either following the beginning of a string or a `_`) will be in a match group.  This means with the string `this_is_filename.rb`, you will match `t` (group 1: `t`), `_i` (group 1: `i`), and `_f` (group 1: `f`).  You can then replace the match with an uppercase version of the first group.  Sorry for my lack of a better example, but in PHP you could do this:

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/(?:\A|_)(\w)/',
    function($matches) {
        return strtoupper($matches[1]);
    },
    'this_is_filename.rb'
);
```

This expression works by capturing either the beginning of a string (`\A`) or an underscore in a non-capturing group, followed by a "word" character (`\w`) that is wrapped in the first match group.  That way you can replace the underscore and the character by the uppercase version of the first match group.

Comment: He is using vim. Which has its own regex language.

Comment: @FDinoff that's what it looked like, however I don't know anything outside of the `:%s/pattern/replace/g` syntax..hopefully my answer can still be of some help.

Comment: Take a look at `:h substitute()` it is basically just the command line function except it is a function and takes in what it should replace.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @FDinoff. This is why I love SO, I feel like I learn just as much as I contribute. I upvoted yours, but I'll leave mine here so I can help potentially someone else outside of vim. *Side note, I need to improve my vim skills.*